# Ex: Can I write it this way and is it grammatically correct, as the additional phrase in the end of a question sounds weird?

Tags: grammar, phrases, questions, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Questions with subordinate (declarative) clauses at the end sound weird.

For example:

> Can you grant me access to the document, since it is currently
>   unavailable?
>
> Where do I submit this, as the normal channel is closed?
>
> Can you come back tomorrow, for he is currently unavailable?

While I understand that you can *switch the position* of the clause to the beginning or simply split them into *two sentences*, are these sentences still grammatically correct?

Edit: Stop saying why join the clauses at all! Those sentences are examples that doesnt have any meaning. Of course I know you can write it as such "Can you grant me access to the document? It is currently unavailable." But how does suggesting another way to rewrite my sentence into two answer my question??? I'm bring this up to figure this out, not to get answers on how to make one sentence two.

Comment: "For" (meaning "because") is literary, so it sounds really weird/awkward using it in a sentence like this.

Comment: It's too bad that the question mark combines both intonation and termination.

Comment: Why would you *not* move the dependent clauses to the start of the sentences? What are you gaining by keeping the order as it is? (Even the answer that was given looks more strange than just reversing the order.) Although, actually, I can't see the reason for these *particular* dependent clauses in the first place. Except possibly the third one—and reversing the order would definitely be the most normal way of expressing that.

Comment: @Jason this is for purely discussion purposes, of course. I am gaining knowledge from asking this  question (/s). I would not recommend my students to use this structure in writing. All I want to know is whether this is grammatically correct, as I often hear/use them in daily verbal conversations.

Comment: Yes you can write the sentences that way. They are grammatical. Far worse sentences have been written in English.

Comment: Why join the clauses at all? "Can you grant me access to the document? It is currently unavailable." It is often easier to read short sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this kind of structure is allowed grammatically, even though the results are sometimes awkward.  One way of keeping the order of the clauses, while clarifying that the question really belongs to the first clause, might be to parenthesize the second clause:

> Can you grant me access to the document (since it is currently unavailable)?

I'm speaking less from positive knowledge than intuition here, and I'm sure someone will want to give you the real technical answer to your question—and I'll be curious about the answer too!

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion for using parenthesis is great! I will be using that from now on.